# zlib.Gzip doesn't work in node.js

Tags: node.js, zlib

I'm trying to compress a html string in node.js (v4/v5/v6). It works fine with deflate but gzip just hangs. Anybody any ideas?

```
var data="<html><head.....        "; //HTML document
zlib.deflate(data, function(err, buffer) {
    //WORKS :)
});

zlib.Gzip(data, function(err, buffer) {
    //HANGS :(
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`zlib.gzip()`](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib_gzip_buf_options_callback) (lowercase `g`).

Comment: It works, thanks! There is a gzip and Gzip function. It's not particularly clear in the documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html

Comment: Yeah, `zlib.Gzip` is actually a class (that's used internally by `zlib.gzip()`, I assume).